# Series convergence or divergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series, absolute-convergence

I'm having a hard time determining if the following series converges (absolutely?) or diverges:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1 {2+\sin n}$$

I would really appreciate some help here. Thanks!

Comment: The series diverges by the Comparison test.

Comment: Are you sure you mean sin(n) and not sin(i)?  Either way you can use comparison to show divergence

Comment: How can there be any convergence or divergence if there is no limit being taken? Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that we have 
$$0 \leq \dfrac{1}{2 + 1} \leq \frac{1}{2+\sin(k)}$$

for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Since $\sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} {\dfrac{1}{3}}$ diverges, by the Comparison test, the sum 
$$\sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}}\dfrac{1}{2+ \sin(k)}$$

diverges.

Answer (score 3):

The "infinite" sum diverges ($\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} c_n \not = 0$) . But your finite sum should converge, just add all the terms together up to n.

Comment: Won't all sums of finite length converge (as long as all elements are finite, of course)?

Comment: Yes. As long as they are finite, add up term by term will give convergence.

Comment: But is convergence even an interesting or useful concept for finite-length sequences and their sums?

Comment: It certainly does. For example algebraic manipulation on sum can be very strange if doing it on infinite sum (for example, sum of all natural number is $-\frac{1}{12}$). In applied fields, I believe finite sums are used more often.

Comment: My comments are about the usefulness of the convergence concept for *finite* sums, yet your reply asserts the usefulness of the concept for infinite sums. I think we're talking past each other

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac1{2+\sin n}\neq0$ Hence the series diverges.

Answer (score 0):

The terms do not approach $0$ since $1 \le 2+\sin n \le 3$, so $\dfrac 1 3 \le \dfrac 1 {2+\sin n}$.  Therefore the series diverges.